# Modal View With Current Context Display in Full Screen in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, ipad

As you can see from the first image attached, in our application we have a split view controller that contains 
in the master: a tab bar controller.
in the detail: a navigation controller with a root.

[image: Application Setup]

Whenever we try to present a modal view controller from the master view (from the button that says 'Do Stuff'), instead of the new view controller being displayed in the same frame as the master, it is displayed in full screen size as seen in the second screenshot.
We have already set the modal presentation style to 'Current Context'
We tried to set the master as 'Defines Context' and 'Provides Context' with no luck.
We also tried to set 'Current Context' in all view controllers in the storyboard, no luck either.

[image: Full Screen View Controller instead of Current Context]

Funnily, if you rotate the device just once to Portrait and back to Landscape, the modal view controller is displayed correctly (not full screen, just the same frame as the master).

This is not an issue in iOS 7. Everything works perfect in 7. It only happens in iOS 8.

P.S. we tried to create all views both using StoryBoards and programatically. Same issue.

Has anyone come across this issue? and know how to fix it?

Comment: Have a look at your size classes (new in iOS 8). I've been wrestling with the same issue for a few hours and realised that if you have the size classes enabled you will need to "install" certain elements for different size classes.

Comment: I've used "Over Current Context" and it works as needed. My problem now is that the app crashes after showing the modal then rotating the device.  @hishamaus have you found a solution? Can't seem to find a way to mimic how Contacts app does it.

Comment: @zejesago Unfortunately not. I have given up on the issue to be honest. We are not using sizeClasses just yet, so we are stuck with the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Current Context is deprecated in iOS8. Use "Over Current Context" instead. 
Here is what you need to do. 
If iOS8 than present "over current context". If iOS7 present "current context".